# laravel: multiple select query

Tags: php, laravel

I understand that to do a select query is

```
$bearLawly = Bear::where('name', '=', 'Lawly')->first();
```

but how to I do a select query such as

```
SELECT * FROM bear where name = 'abc' AND age => '5' AND title = 'kid' ORDER BY name LIMIT 5, 10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$bearLawly = Bear::where('name', 'abc') // By default = will be used, so optional
                 ->where('age', '>=', '5')
                 ->where('title', 'kid')
                 ->orderBy('name') // or orderBy('name', 'desc') for reverse
                 ->take(5)->skip(10)->get();
```

According to following query:

```
SELECT * FROM bear where name = 'abc' AND age => '5' AND title = 'kid' ORDER BY name LIMIT 5, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain them:

```
$bearLawly = Bear::where('name', 'Lawly')->where('age', '5')->first();
```

Comment: what if i don't want just the first found but 'ORDER BY name LIMIT 5, 10' ?